# Construction of places of worship in a Muslim majority country

Tags: islamic-government

Assalam Alaikum,

Recently work on a hindu temple being constructed in Islamabad, Pakistan was halted and it is now being said that it needs to be checked whether a place of worship for a group other than Muslims can be funded from public money. Since Pakistan is a Muslim majority country and an Islamic Republic, the matter becomes tricky.
(Source: https://www.dawn.com/news/1567777/real-issue-funding-not-construction-of-hindu-temple-noorul-haq-qadri)

So the parts of the question are:

1. Can a new church, synagogue or temple be constructed at all in a Muslim majority country?
2. Can public funds be used for such a construction?

The constitution of Pakistan guarantees protection for places of worship of all religions as well as practice of these religions. But this is being interpreted to mean existing places of worship, and not building new ones.

Additionally, if mosques are being built using the national exchequer, then it stands to reason that the same should apply for churches, temples etc.

Does anyone have any knowledge about this? At best with an example from the Prophet's (SAW) life?

Thank you!

Comment: @UmH Well it answers the question partially. The basis for refusing construction is derived from general Quranic verses and Hadith. I am looking for either concrete example from the life of the Prophet (SAW) or the Rashidun Caliphate where such a decision was made. As such I am not satisfied with the answer in the mentioned question.

Comment: That is your choice, however IMO the evidence from the hadith is specific and clear and as stated in the answer there is also Ijma' that it is prohibited so the case is strong. It is also well known that in the pact that Umar ibn al-Khatab made with the people of Shaam he imposed the condition that they not construct any new places of worship, and this was in their own settlements so it would apply doubly so to Muslim cities. Similar is also narrated from Ibn Abbas and the tabieen.